# Concurrent iteration and deletion from Set in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a pre-populated set of strings. I want to iterate over the items and while iterating, i need to "do work" which might also remove the item from the set. I want to spawn a new thread for each item's "do work". Please note that only some items are removed from the set during "do work".

Now i have the following question,

Can i achieve this by simply using Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet()); ? I am guessing this will throw up ConcurrentModificationException since i am removing items from the list while i am iterating. How can i achieve the above behavior efficiently without consistency issues ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
List<Future<String>> toRemove = new ARraysList<>();
for(String s: set)
   toRemove.add(es.submit(new Task(s)));
for(Future<String> future : toRemove()) {
   String s = future.get();
   if (s != null)
       set.remove(s);
}
```

This avoids needing to access the collection in a multi-threaded way.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I want to remove the elements in the tasks instead of clearing the set at the end. This is because i have a logic which decides whether to remove the element or not. So all the elements need not be removed at the end. I apologize for the lack of clarity in my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a master **producer** thread that will remove the elements from the collection and will feed them to **consumer** threads. The consumer threads have no need to "personally" remove the items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a SynchronisedSet will still throw ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Try this:

```
Set s = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap())
```

ConcurrentHashMap should never throw a ConcurrentModificationException, when multiple threads are accessing and modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on the relation between the data in your set and the successful completion of the operation.

### Remove from Set is independent of the result of task execution

If you don't care about the actual result of the thread execution, you can just go through the set and remove every item as you dispatch the task  (you have some examples of that already)

### Remove from Set only if task execution completed successfully

If the deletion from the set should be transactional to the success of the execution, you could use `Future`s to collect information about the success of the task execution. That way, only successfully executed items will be deleted from the original set. There's no need to access the Set structure concurrently, as you can separate execution from check using `Future`s and an `ExecutorService` . eg:

```
// This task will execute the job and, 
// if successful, return the string used as context
class Task implements Callable<String> {
    final String target;
    Task(String s) {
        this.target = s; 
    }
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // do your stuff
        // throw an exception if failed 
        return target;
    }
}
```

And this is how it's used:

```
ExecutorService executor;

Set<Callable<String>> myTasks = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();
for(String s: set) {
   myTasks.add(new Task(s));
}
List<Future<String>> results = executor.invoqueAll(myTasks);
for (Future<String> result:results) {
    try {
        set.remove(result.get());
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        // the task failed during execution - handle as required
    } catch (CancellationException ce) {
        // the task was cancelled - handle as required
    }
}
```